# Registering sidebar with or without hook

Tags: wordpress, widget

I'm little bit confused on it. When registering sidebar in a function file of Wordpress, we use register_sidebar() function and pass arguments in it.

Without using any action hook, the sidebar works very fine. However, in the codex i've seen a action hook named 'widget_init' is used to register sidebar. So, my confusion is what is the standard approach to register a sidebar, with or without action hook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this interesting piece](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/08/sidebars-in-wordpress) on registering sidebars which says

> **Bad sidebar code**
>
> There are some common things I would like to see changed within
> themes. Not all of these things are technically incorrect, but they
> can present some unintended consequences or are just needless bits of
> code.
>
> **Problem #1: Randomly dropping code into functions.php**
>
> If you’re a theme developer, you should be familiar with WordPress’
> built-in hooks. Not only should you be familiar with them, you should
> actually be using them.
>
> The biggest issue I see is sidebar code just being dropped into
> functions.php. You should create a sidebar registration function and
> hook it to widgets_init. You can see an example of this in the
> “Registering a dynamic sidebar” section above.
>
> The reason this is important is so that child themes (and even
> plugins) can know exactly when a sidebar was registered. This gives
> child themes the opportunity unregister a sidebar if needed. Plus, not
> doing it this way is just plain sloppy.

---

> As a sidenote to this: You should never just drop code into
> functions.php. Always use the hooks WordPress provides to execute your
> functions when they should be executed in the WordPress flow.

Comment: Thank you Wali Hassan. Its start making sense to me !